# Инвалидация структуры с константной ссылкой-полем

Tags: c++, ссылки

Здесь:

using namespace std;

```
struct S
{
    int x;
    const int &y;
};

int main()
{
    //S x{1,2};
    S* p = new S{1,2};
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь с p всё нормально, но что с y? Говорят, теперь второе поле этой структуры не валидно.
Так писано в стандарте: во отличие от закомментированной строки, полное выражение кончается на new, и объект (2), которому продлили жизнь, всё равно помер.

Но в чём именно это проявляется? Я могу вывести
((*p).y) и получить 2, могу взять адрес от этого выражения.

То есть, Как это понять? Какие проблемы будут? В каком коде будет разница при общении с x и *p ?

Comment: Переход на красный свет проявляется в экономии времени. Как правило все остаются живы-здоровы до поры до времени. Однако правила запрещают, так как рано или поздно вас собьют.

Comment: Конкретно в этом случае ссылка указывает на память, которая больше не принадлежит конкретному временному объекту. В вашем конкретном случае вам повезло и в соответствующих (никому не нужных) байтах хранится значение `2`. В более сложной ситуации несколько таких объектов могут случайно разделить одну и ту же область памяти и ... А вообще, это неопределённое поведение - может произойти всё что угодно. Ваша программа больше не является корректной программой на C++. Компилятор, компоновщик, система исполнения умывают руки, не дают никаких гарантий относительно того что будет. Никаких гарантий.

Comment: ... но вы можете сами проверить получившийся машинный код. Если он делает то что вам нужно, вам гарантии и не нужны. Помните что проверку надо делать после каждой компиляции.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не трогайте орфографию в моём тексте. Не надо менять строчные на заглавные, помер на умер и так далее. Это вот вообще не ваше дело, разве нет? Это я написал, имею право именно так выражаться.

Comment: Если вы не хотите чтобы ваш вопрос трогали, лучше его удалить. Это общий ресурс, много людей просматривают и правят вопросы и ответы на предмет грамматики, лексики и оформления.

Comment: Одно дело, если вопрос не понятен, не выделен код итп.

Другое дело - менять мне лексику, которая не является ругательной. Тут же не уроки русского, и тем более стилистики. Как можно не понимать, что тронуть чужой текст - это то же, что и чужую вещь, это не всем нравится и на это нужна причина более серьёзная, чем "умер - более литературное, чем помер"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим ассемблерный код `g++ -std=c++17 -O0 -S -fverbose-asm rvalp.cpp` :

```
        movq    %rsp, %rbp      #,
        pushq   %rbx    #
        subq    $24, %rsp       #,
# rvalp.cpp:10:     S* p = new S{1,2};
        movl    $2, -28(%rbp)   #, D.2080
        leaq    -28(%rbp), %rbx #, _3
        movl    $16, %edi       #,
        call    _Znwm   #
        movl    $1, (%rax)      #, MEM[(struct S *)_6].x
        movq    %rbx, 8(%rax)   # _3, MEM[(struct S *)_6].y
        movq    %rax, -24(%rbp) # _5, p
# rvalp.cpp:11:     return 0;
        movl    $0, %eax        #, _11
# rvalp.cpp:12: }
        addq    $24, %rsp       #,
        popq    %rbx    #
        popq    %rbp    #
        ret
```

адрес стека копируем в `rbp` :

```
movq    %rsp, %rbp
```

временное число 2 храним в стеке :

```
movl    $2, -28(%rbp)
```

адрес этого места в стеке записываем в `rbx` :

```
leaq    -28(%rbp), %rbx
```

выделяем память для этого объекта :

```
call    _Znwm
```

записываем все элементы структуры по адресу `rax` :

```
movl    $1, (%rax)
movq    %rbx, 8(%rax)
```

В итоге ссылка `const int &y;` указывает на место в стеке, где хранился временный объект и любой дальнейший ход программы всё сотрёт. Так как адрес `-28(%rbp)` глубже адреса последней переменной `-24(%rbp)` **p**.

---

В случае `S x{1,2};` временный объект `2` (`-4(%rbp)`)будет хранится выше по стеку и затираться будет после переменной `x` (`-24(%rbp)`).

```
# rvalp.cpp:9:     S x{1,2};
    movl    $2, %eax        #, _1
    movq    $0, -32(%rbp)   #, x
    movq    $0, -24(%rbp)   #, x
    movl    $1, -32(%rbp)   #, x.x
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)  # _1, D.2091
    leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax  #, tmp90
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp) # tmp90, x.y
```